# react-lottie: Animation would not show

Tags: reactjs, lottie

Using react-lottie version 1.2.3 to try animate in React web application.

It successfully compiled without any error message but the animation would not show from json file.

I have followed [React Lottie not showing animation not showing (web)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61845933/react-lottie-not-showing-animation-not-showing-web) which suggested replace `animationData: animationData` to `animationData: animationData.default`. Have tried both however it did not work.

Any ideas?

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Lottie from 'react-lottie';
import animationData from './lottie/lottie_page_not_found.json';

class PageNotFound extends Component {
  render(){
    const defaultOptions = {
      loop: true,
      autoplay: true,
      animationData: animationData.default,
      rendererSettings: {
        preserveAspectRatio: "xMidYMid slice"
      }
    };

    return(
      <div>
         <h1 style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>Page Not Found</h1>
          <Lottie
            options={defaultOptions}
            height={400}
            width={400}
          />
       </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PageNotFound;
```